# Common Lisp unbound variable / defmacro

Tags: variables, lambda, common-lisp

I need to make the function defmacro for my meta-circular interpreter that can read this syntax:

```
pseudoscheme> (defmacro (minus x y) (list ‘- y x))
MINUS


pseudoscheme> (expand-macro '(minus 3 2))
(- 3 2)
```

When I use this:

```
(defmacro my-defmacro ((name &rest args) &body  body)
    (let ((form (gensym))(env (gensym)))
        (progn 
        `(setf (macro-function ',name)    
            (lambda (,form ,env))
                (destructuring-bind ,args (rest, form) ,@body))
        name
        )   
    )
)
```

and then:

```
(my-defmacro (min a b)(list '- a b))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: The variable MIN is unbound.
```

I can't understand why.

-----EDITED-----
If I use this:

```
(defmacro my-defmacro ((name &rest args) &body  body)
    (let ((form (gensym))(env (gensym)))
        `(progn (setf (macro-function ',name)
            (lambda (,form ,env))
                (destructuring-bind ,args (rest, form) ,@body))
         ',name)    
    )
)
```

and then:

```
(my-defmacro (min a b)(list '- a b))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Odd number of args to SETF: ((MACRO-FUNCTION (QUOTE PLUS)) (LAMBDA (#:G786 #:G787)) (DESTRUCTURING-BIND (A B) (REST #:G786) (LIST # A B)))
```

Comment: Neither can we.  The first time `PLUS` appears in this question is in your error message.  It doesn't appear _anywhere_ in your code.  You're not showing use the code that you're actually using.  Furthermore, you said that you want to be able to do `(defmacro (minus x y) (list ‘- y x))`, but then you actually did `(my-defmacro (min a b)(- a b))`.  Please do what you said you were going to do, and show us the results of that.

Comment: How is this different from your other question with almost the same content [redefine defmacro in LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048226/redefine-defmacro-in-lisp)?

Comment: Regardless of all other things, you don't need `progn` inside `let`, `let` already acts as implicit `progn`.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor, corrected the question, the problem is the same anyway. i use my-defmacro just for avoiding the request of redefine my defmacro function but if i can use defmacro instead of my-defmacro could be better.

Comment: @Sylwester i already ask (flag to a moderator) for close that question cause i make a big mistake and i don't know how make all more clear :/

Answer (score 0):

Your `my-defmacro` works for you host CL system, but I get the feeling you want macro capabilities in your interpreter and this won't do it. (except if ythe interpreter environment is the global host implementations environment, but that would make a lot of challenges)

I don't know how you do compound procedures in your evaluator but when my evaluator gets a `(lambda (x) (+ x x))` it is turned into `(compound-procedure <env> (x) (+ x x))`. My macros turn into almost the same except the first element is `compound-syntax`.

Every evaluated operator has a tag which tells it what it is (one of primitive-syntax, primitive-procedure, compound-syntax, compound-procedure) and I only need a general way of dealing with those 4.

The real difference between a compound procedure and compound syntax is that the arguments gets evaluated for a procedure and in a compound syntax the result gets evaluated.

So. Have you implemented so that ((lambda (x) (+ x x)) 5) works? Well, then you'll almost implemented macros as well. This is of course not true for a compiler, since this approach would expand the code every time it's run instead of expanding once when the closure gets created. (Optimizations is no way to go on the first version anyway)

Comment: The custom defmacro doesn't work though. Note that it's just returning `name`, not a form that will set a macro function. That's why the error is occurring. It needs to be `(progn (setf ...) ',name).

Answer (score 0):

For your 'edited code' you have a misplaced paren:

```
(defmacro my-defmacro ((name &rest args) &body  body)
    (let ((form (gensym))(env (gensym)))
        `(progn (setf (macro-function ',name)
            (lambda (,form ,env))                    ;; <== HERE
                (destructuring-bind ,args (rest, form) ,@body))
         ',name)    
    )
)
```

which leads to `setf` having three subforms.  Rewrite it like this (while using standard Lisp formatting):

```
(defmacro my-defmacro ((name &rest args) &body  body)
  (let ((form (gensym))
        (env  (gensym)))
    `(progn (setf (macro-function ',name)
                  (lambda (,form ,env)
                    (destructuring-bind ,args (rest, form) 
                      ,@body)))
            ',name)))
```